# Windows Taskbar Icons not Showing

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons, gui

For some reason, this past week, the icons on my taskbar are not showing as expected. I've tried all solutions that I could find but nothing seems to work, do you think there are any solutions i haven't tried? I've tried restoring windows (twice). It seems that the image icon for the apps are not loading. When I go on windows search it will show Spotify with a blank document icon, I am guessing this has to do with the taskbar problem.

--Update--
I have also noticed that certain app icons are also not appearing, and that the groove music icon for mp3 files is also not showing.

[image: This is what the issue looks like]

[image: missing app icon]

[image: missing groove music mp3 icons]

Comment: Run DISM / SFC  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Which programs are showing these blank icons?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Tried all solutions." In that case, how can you expect to get any help? You've tried **everything**.

Comment: For Clarification, the apps not showing their icons are: Armoury Crate, Mail (Stock Microsoft app), Spotify, Xbox, Groove Music, Minecraft Launcher, and Settings.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: I tried the command prompt suggestion by John in the comments, although I don't know how to use command promt.

Comment: Before going further, clear your icon cache.  Reboot.  Google "windows 10 clear icon cache" for simple instructions.  This sometimes works, sometimes does not.  Never hurts.  I have yet to have DISM or SFC fix a single problem.  It says "files repaired" or whatever.. but I still have the problem I started with.  I am not saying they don't work but I have yet to see a single person say "YES! That worked for me."  It too is harmless so can't hurt to try.